# admob test ad not showing upp

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I created a new project. And I added an admob ad to it.

I'm sure there are no errors in the codes

because I did the same looking at a video

How long do I have to wait for test ads to appear? or does it come out right away?

I waited an hour. The test ad does not appear.

I'll add some pictures and code. Can you help me. Thanks

[image]

[image]

the codes I use

Activitymain.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    private AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                }
            });
            
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);

        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                    // covers the screen.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClicked() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                    // to the app after tapping on an ad.
```

Build gradle

```
applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp3"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the metadata for App-ID on manifest xml under application tag
like:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
```

Comment: hello first of all, thanks for everything. When I run the apk on someone else's phone, the advertisement appears. I tried it on 4 people and they all show ads. It just didn't show me either. Do I need to use the code you provided?

Comment: @Cebom25  If the ads show on other devices then that means you already added the code above on your manifest. You can try the latest sdk:  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'